Setting default CRON expression for TimerTrigger outside of local.settings.json
I have an Azure Functions Timer job in which the CRON expression is fetched from local.settings.json for local development, and from the Function App's App Settings for production environments.
public static void MyTimerJob([TimerTrigger("%MyTimerCRON%")] TimerInfo Timer, ILogger Log) {    
    // Function code 
}

What is the proper way to set a default value for MyTimerCRON in case this value is not set in the deployed environment's App Settings?
In order to have a default value in case nothing is set on the App Settings when deploying, I tried to add a new configuration source that would be propagated to production environments by following the steps as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources:

Adding the providers to the ConfigurationBuilder property of IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder in ConfigureAppConfiguration

public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

    builder.ConfigurationBuilder
        .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
}


Ensured the file is copied to the function app's output folder in the .csproj file:

<None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>      
</None>


And added the respective appsettings.json:

{
    "MyTimerCRON": "* * * * *",
}

But when running the App, I am greeted with both these messages:
[2024-11-06T18:33:25.565Z] The Functions scale controller may not scale the following functions correctly because some configuration values were modified in an external startup class.
[2024-11-06T18:33:25.566Z]   Function 'MyTimerJob' uses the modified key(s): %MyTimerCRON%

and while the Timer job actually executes, if I try to run
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyTimerCRON")

the value returned is null, which makes me believe that the .AddEnvironmentVariable done at startup didn't have the intended effect...

Here, you have to add dependency in program.cs to get triggered  and below code worked for me:
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "rithcron": "0 */1 * * * *"
  }
}

program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var rithcho = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((cxt, cho) =>
    {
        cho.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        cho.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        var rith = cxt.Configuration["rithcron"]; 
        cho.AddSingleton(new RithTest { RiC = rith });
    })
    .Build();

rithcho.Run();

public class RithTest
{
    public string RiC { get; set; }
}

Function.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace RithFuncApp
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger ri_lgr;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            ri_lgr = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("%rithcron%")] TimerInfo ritim)
        {
            ri_lgr.LogInformation($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        }
    }
}

Output:

